# How to convert float64 to json.Number golang

Tags: go

I have ,

```
  {"time": 14990, "timeTaken": 5.43420481682}
```

I want timeTaken as json.Number so I am trying this -

```
  {"time": 14990, "timeTaken": json.Number(5.43420481682)}
```

But it is not working.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  Using the `float64` directly should have an identical effect.

Answer (score 3):

`json.Number` is internally, a string. Using `strconv.FormatFloat` should work.

```
json.Number(strconv.FormatFloat(123.456, 'e', -1, 64))
```